# IdentityServer3 call of Autofac `RegisterApiControllers()` fails on Mono 6.4+ with `TypeLoadException`

Tags: c#, mono, autofac, identityserver3

We've been using IdentityServer3 2.5.4 with Mono 4.8 for some time, running on Ubuntu & MacOS.

We've upgraded to Mono 6.6, and we now get an exception on startup:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 
    'Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtector:_protector' (0) 
    due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000107 from typeref 
    (expected class 'System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector' 
    in assembly 'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') 
    assembly:System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a 
    type:System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector 
    member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeTypeHandle.type_is_assignable_from(System.Type,System.Type)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo (System.RuntimeType type, System.RuntimeType target) [0x00000] in <285579f54af44a2ca048dad6be20e190>:0
  at System.RuntimeType.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type c) [0x00020] in <285579f54af44a2ca048dad6be20e190>:0
  at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.RegistrationExtensions.<RegisterApiControllers>b__0 (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <03d9eb8289e046799e444fc1f976e306>:0
  [...]
  at IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.AutofacConfig.Configure (IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.IdentityServerOptions options) [0x004ef] in <03d9eb8289e046799e444fc1f976e306>:0
```

(Edited for readability.)

Autofac is scanning the `IdentityServer3.dll` assembly to register its WebApi controllers when it hits the exception.

`Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtector` is a private member of this assembly (according to `monop -p`), which I guess is why it's being found by the scan.

I've tried other Mono versions betwee 4.8 & 6.6; it only occurs for Mono 6.4 & above.

Other versions:

- Autofac 3.5.2
- Autofac.Owin 3.1.0
- Autofac.WebApi2 3.4.0
- Autofac.WebApi2.Owin 3.3.0

I'd appreciate any ideas about how to solve this problem.